# Optimization with Matrix value constraint

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I am trying to find the orientation and position of a polygon resting on a curved surface under gravity.The polygon **MUST** not be penetrated by any part of the surface below. Here is an example for a square shape.[image]

The curved surface is defined by a 2D Matrix: Tdata. The problem can be formulated to a constrained Optimization problem.
The initial square can be approximated by five points(four vertices and one center point):

```
ConVer = {{l/2, w/2, 0}, {l/2, -w/2,0}, {-l/2, -w/2, 0}, {-l/2, w/2,0}, {0, 0, 0}};
```

Where l is the length and w is the width of the Square.

The square's orientation is parameterized by three angles:

```
Rθ = RotationMatrix[θ, {0, 0, 1}];
Rψ = RotationMatrix[ψ, {0, 1, 0}];
Rϕ = RotationMatrix[ϕ, {1, 0, 0}];
```

Then the parameterized square is

```
For[i = 1, i < 6, i++, ConVer[[i]] =Rθ.Rψ.Rϕ.ConVer[[i]] + {x, y,z}];
```

Where {x ,y ,z} is the coordinates of the center point of the square.

The optimization uses NMinimize function:

```
x = 1; y = 1; θ = 0;
NMinimize[{z,
             Tdata[(ConVer[[1]])[[1 ;; 2]]] <= (ConVer[[1]])[[3]] &&
             Tdata[(ConVer[[2]])[[1 ;; 2]]] <= (ConVer[[2]])[[3]] &&        
             Tdata[(ConVer[[3]])[[1 ;; 2]]] <= (ConVer[[3]])[[3]] &&
             Tdata[(ConVer[[4]])[[1 ;; 2]]] <= (ConVer[[4]])[[3]] &&
             Tdata[(ConVer[[5]])[[1 ;; 2]]] <= (ConVer[[5]])[[3]]}, 
            {{ψ, -Pi/4, Pi/4}, {ϕ, -Pi/4, Pi/4}, {z, 0, 1}}];
```

When Tdata is a 2d function this works well, but as to 2d Matrix error occurs! Why is that?
I also tried to solve this problem in Matlab using 'fmincon', and Matlab can return desired result.

Comment: You need to leave a blank line before code snippets, otherwise they are treated as part of the text of the previous paragraph.

Comment: What type of error?

Comment: NMinimize::bcons, which means my constraints are invalid

Comment: Please give an example on how do you want to define `Tdata[]` as a "2D matrix"

Comment: The curved surface is defined by Tdata as follows:f[{x_, y_}] := ( Cos[x] + Sin[y])/3;
Tdata = Flatten[
  Table[Flatten[{i, j, N[f /@ {{i, j}}]}], {i, 0, 6.5, 0.5}, {j, 0, 
    6.5, 0.5}], 1]

Comment: `Tdata[(ConVer[[1]])[[1 ;; 2]]]` et al do not evaluate to anything that can be used in inequalities. It's not at all clear what you want for your actual inequalities. I will also mention that I cannot really follow the setup of your problem. Not sure what is `w` or why you use five points to describe your plane (three should be sufficient, so do the other two have some physical significance?) What are you solving for? Is it `w` or rotation angles or `z` or ...?

Comment: If you want to notice someone of you comment reply, you can "ping" them (using "at"username). In this case: @DanielLichtblau... (BTW you are talking about a polygon shape, not a plane, right?).

Comment: @Yves Klett, Thanks for your tips! Any ideas for optimization methods? Matlab solves the problem using active set method, is there a similar function in Mathematica.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, Perhaps my description is unclear. Imagine the plane is a plate which cannot be penetrated. I use five points to replace the plane for the sake of simplification. The solution I'm trying to find is the two angles and one height value of the center of the plane.